# Start iterating vector from the nth element

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm trying to iterate a vector from the *nth* element onwards. Not sure how should i go about doing this.

I have a vector *A* and *B*. My vector *A* has 10 elements of *PC1-PC10* and my vector *B* has 20 elements of *User1-User20*.
So what I want to do is that when both my vector *A* and *B* reaches the 10th element, meaning to say the last element for vector *A*, I want to repeat iterating vector *A* but start iterating vector *B* from the *11th* element so that I can do some stuff with it.

Below is the simplified code that I came up with but technically its about the same thing:

```
vector<string>::iterator b = vecB.begin();
for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
    for (vector<string>::iterator a = vecA.begin(); a != vecA.end() ; a++) {
        if (a == vecA.end()) {
            b = vecB.begin() + 10; //here the iterator for verB should start from the 11th element
        }
    ++b
    }
}
```

Should I mess with the iterator for vector *B*? Or is there another alternative?

**EDIT**
It seems that I have been asking the wrong question after all. I have marked the answer to this question and will be posting another shortly. Thanks for the quick response to my question!

Comment: Check if find can help you, if you know the element

Comment: Do you intend to iterate both vectors for the first 10 elements simultaneously? Currently you never increment `b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `if` condition inside the nested loop will never be true, because it conflicts with the loop condition:

```
for (vector<string>::iterator a = vecA.begin(); a != vecA.end() ; a++) {
// This check ----------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// guarantees that this will never succeed:
//      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    if (a == vecA.end()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You should rewrite the code like this:

```
vector<string>::iterator b = vecB.begin();
// Check that vecB has sufficient number of elements before entering the loop.
for (int i = 1 ; i < 2 ; i++) {
    for (vector<string>::iterator a = vecA.begin(); a != vecA.end() ; ++a, ++b) {
        ...
    }
    // At this point we know for sure that a == vecA.end(),
    // because it is a post-condition of the for loop above.
    b = std::next(vecB.begin(), 11);
}
```

The call of `++b` can be moved into the loop header.

Note the use of `std::next`: although

```
b = vecB.begin() + 10;
```

compiles for vectors, it is not guaranteed for all kinds of containers. Use [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) instead:

```
b = std::next(vecB.begin(), 11);
```

**Note:** This code makes an assumption that `vecB` has at least 11 elements more than `vecA` does. This may be OK if you check that assumption before entering the loop. If this assumption is broken, the code would have undefined behavior.

Comment: @BaummitAugen It is going to work for vectors, but if you switch the container to something else, `it + 10` may not compile. That's the reason `std::advance` and `std::next` were introduced in the first place.

Comment: I think at the very least you should qualify "often compiles and " "is not guaranteed" because it really reads like it applies to `std::vector`.

Comment: your answer assumes, that vecB will always have at least 10 elements, I wouldn't do that (even if OP says so, it's better to propose safer solution). You could always check, if vecA ended on 10th element if it's required for proper behaviour.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `next(..., 10)`?

Comment: @BaummitAugen It looks like OP really wanted 11, because `++b` in his code is after the conditional, with nothing in between. He also says "start iterating vector B from the 11th element". I'm sure he'll be able to adjust the constant as needed, though.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already answered how to reset or advance an iterator, so I'll just answer, how to solve your problem in a simpler way. It's much simpler to iterate two vectors in parallel using the index rather than two iterators:

```
// assumes vecB is bigger than vecA as described in the question
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vecB.size(); i++) {
    auto user = vecB[i];
    auto pc = vecA[i % vecA.size()];
}
```

Pay attention to how the smaller vector is iterated using the remainder operator.

Comment: vector sizes are of type `unsigned int` (though it is unlikely your vector size would ever rollover the max value of a signed int)

Comment: @RPGillespie a fair point. I corrected the type. `unsigned int` may overflow too. `std::vector<std::string>::size_type` would be the actual type but... that's kinda verbose. `std::size_t` should be correct on most if not all implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the iterator for B, it will automatically continue with 11th element. But you need to restart iteration on A at the beginning of the for loop (or you would work with `a.end()` which is not a valid element):

```
if (a == vecA.end()) {
    a = vecA.begin();
}
```

Also you should iterate over both but check for end on `b` only; if you check on `a`, the `for` would end before the `if` would turn true:

```
for (auto a = vecA.begin(), b = vecB.begin(); b != vecB.end(); ++a, ++b)
```

You can see the whole code [here](http://ideone.com/XCR2Ij).

Comment: and then you skip first element of vecA in second iteration

Comment: No, you don't. You need to have it `for { if {}; doSomething;}`. If you would have it `for { doSomething;  if {}; }`, you would work with `a.end()` before the `if` which is wrong.

Comment: so refine it in your answer

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `std::next`, as shown in the answer by @dasblinkenlight, you can also use `std::advance`.

```
b = vecB.begin();
std::advance(b, 10);
```

Comment: I do not think this answers the question. OP only wants to advance `std::vector::iterator` which works fine the way he does it. He asks how to cleanly iterate his `vector`s.

Comment: `std::advance` cleanly advances `std::vector::iterator`. The fact that it can also advance other iterators does not make it unclean for `std::vector::iterator` or less clean than incrementing the iterator in your own function.

Comment: But *"How do I advance arbitrary iterators?"*  is not the question, nor does it solve the problem. The problem is that his loops are wrong, not that `it + 10` does not work for `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score -1):

I actually prefer to manually iterate over vectors pre-C++11 because it looks way cleaner and more readable than `iterators`:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < my_vector.size(); i++) {
    my_vector[i]; //Do Something
}
```

You can specify the range you want to iterate over simply by modifying the for loop conditional (i.e. `unsigned int i = n`)

Edit: Before downvoting actually read my entire answer. Using iterators on vectors is overly verbose and makes your code virtually unreadable. If there is a legitimate reason this method should not be used in favor of iterators, then please leave a comment.

Most people aren't looking for an ultra-generic, drop-in-any-container solution. Most people know they need a dynamic list, `vector` fits the bill, so why not make your code easy to read for the next guy?

Comment: how does it answer anything?

Comment: @zoska OP said: "I'm trying to iterate a vector from the nth element onwards. Not sure how should i go about doing this." My answer clearly shows how to iterate through a vector from the nth element on.